# how to avoid duplicates in a has_many :through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, duplicates, has-many-through, has-many

How can I achieve the following? I have two models (blogs and readers) and a JOIN table that will allow me to have an N:M relationship between them:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :readers, :through => :blogs_readers
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :blogs, :through => :blogs_readers
end

class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader
end
```

What I want to do now, is add readers to different blogs. The condition, though, is that I can only add a reader to a blog ONCE. So there mustn't be any duplicates (same `readerID`, same `blogID`) in the `BlogsReaders` table. How can I achieve this?

The second question is, how do I get a list of blog that the readers isn't subscribed to already (e.g. to fill a drop-down select list, which can then be used to add the reader to another blog)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about:

```
Blog.find(:all,
          :conditions => ['id NOT IN (?)', the_reader.blog_ids])
```

Rails takes care of the collection of ids for us with association methods! :)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Also, I wanted to mention that this is probably the better method, as the accepted answer selects ALL data from the row(s) (e.g., the_reader.blogs) whereas my answer selects only the ids from the rows (e.g., the_reader.blog_ids). This is a big performance hit!

Comment: this is a better solution and should be the right answer. Thanks Josh.

Answer (score 99):

Simpler solution that's built into Rails:

```
 class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :readers, :through => :blogs_readers, :uniq => true
    end

    class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
     has_many :blogs, :through => :blogs_readers, :uniq => true
    end

    class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :blog
      belongs_to :reader
    end
```

Note adding the `:uniq => true` option to the `has_many` call.

Also you might want to consider `has_and_belongs_to_many` between Blog and Reader, unless you have some other attributes you'd like to have on the join model (which you don't, currently).  That method also has a `:uniq` opiton.

Note that this doesn't prevent you from creating the entries in the table, but it does ensure that when you query the collection you get only one of each object.

**Update**

In Rails 4 the way to do it is via a scope block.  The Above changes to.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent:  :destroy
 has_many :readers,  -> { uniq }, through: :blogs_readers
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :blogs, -> { uniq }, through: :blogs_readers
end

class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader
end
```

**Update for Rails 5**

The use of `uniq` in the scope block will cause an error  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'extensions' for []:Array`. Use `distinct` instead :

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent:  :destroy
 has_many :readers,  -> { distinct }, through: :blogs_readers
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :blogs, -> { distinct }, through: :blogs_readers
end

class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader
end
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with this approach if your join model has any other fields. For example,a positions field so that each child can be positioned within its parent.
`blog.readers << reader  # blog_readers.position = 1;`
`blog.readers << reader  # blog_readers.position = 2`
As second blog_readers has a different position the uniq setting doesn't see it as an existing entry and allows it to be created

Comment: If you have a default scope that orders your blogs, you will need to unscope that (or DISTINCT will fail), you can use this: ```has_many :blogs, -> { unscope(:order).uniq }, through: :blog_readers```

Comment: To update @marksiemers answer for Rails 5.2 `has_many :blogs, -> { unscope(:order).distinct }, through: :blog_readers`

Answer (score 39):

This should take care of your first question:

```
class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader

  validates_uniqueness_of :reader_id, :scope => :blog_id
end
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a long time, and this never occurred to me! Great solution! Thanks!

Comment: Please read carefully about Concurrency and integrity here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: I think this works fine in Rails 5 (working for me anyway)

Answer (score 20):

**The Rails 5.1 way**

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent:  :destroy
 has_many :readers,  -> { distinct }, through: :blogs_readers
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :blogs, -> { distinct }, through: :blogs_readers
end

class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader
end
```

Comment: Reasoning: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9683 and https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/adfab2dcf4003ca564d78d4425566dd2d9cd8b4f

Comment: @pastullo But it is still insert the data in middle table blog_readers . how to prevent that ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer at this link shows how to override the "<<" method to achieve what you are looking for without raising exceptions or creating a separate method: [Rails idiom to avoid duplicates in has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315109/rails-idiom-to-avoid-duplicates-in-has-many-through)

Answer (score 2):

The top answer currently says to use `uniq` in the proc:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent:  :destroy
 has_many :readers,  -> { uniq }, through: :blogs_readers
end
```

This however kicks the relation into an array and can break things that are expecting to perform operations on a relation, not an array.

If you use `distinct` it keeps it as a relation:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, dependent:  :destroy
 has_many :readers,  -> { distinct }, through: :blogs_readers
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking someone will come along with a better answer than this.

```
the_reader = Reader.find(:first, :include => :blogs)

Blog.find(:all, 
          :conditions => ['id NOT IN (?)', the_reader.blogs.map(&:id)])
```

[edit]

Please see Josh's answer below. It's the way to go. (I knew there was a better way out there ;)

Comment: you could also do this in one statement using find_by_sql.

Answer (score 1):

I do the following for Rails 6

```
class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader

  validates :blog_id, uniqueness: { scope: :reader_id }
end
```

Don't forget to create database constraint to prevent violations of a uniqueness.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way is to serialize the relationship into an array:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :readers, :through => :blogs_readers
  serialize :reader_ids, Array
end
```

Then when assigning values to readers, you apply them as

```
blog.reader_ids = [1,2,3,4]
```

When assigning relationships this way, duplicates are automatically removed.