# Rails idiom to avoid duplicates in has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, idioms

I have a standard many-to-many relationship between users and roles in my Rails app:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end
```

I want to make sure that a user can only be assigned any role once.  Any attempt to insert a duplicate should ignore the request, not throw an error or cause validation failure.  What I really want to represent is a "set", where inserting an element that already exists in the set has no effect.  {1,2,3} U {1} = {1,2,3}, not {1,1,2,3}.

I realize that I can do it like this:

```
user.roles << role unless user.roles.include?(role)
```

or by creating a wrapper method (e.g. `add_to_roles(role)`), but I was hoping for some idiomatic way to make it automatic via the association, so that I can write:

```
user.roles << role  # automatically checks roles.include?
```

and it just does the work for me.  This way, I don't have to remember to check for dups or to use the custom method.  Is there something in the framework I'm missing?  I first thought the :uniq option to has_many would do it, but it's basically just "select distinct."

Is there a way to do this declaratively?  If not, maybe by using an association extension?

Here's an example of how the default behavior fails:

```
    >> u = User.create
      User Create (0.6ms)   INSERT INTO "users" ("name") VALUES(NULL)
    => #<User id: 3, name: nil>
    >> u.roles << Role.first
      Role Load (0.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "roles" LIMIT 1
      UserRole Create (0.5ms)   INSERT INTO "user_roles" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES(1, 3)
      Role Load (0.4ms)   SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "user_roles" ON "roles".id = "user_roles".role_id WHERE (("user_roles".user_id = 3)) 
    => [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">]
    >> u.roles << Role.first
      Role Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "roles" LIMIT 1
      UserRole Create (0.5ms)   INSERT INTO "user_roles" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES(1, 3)
    => [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">, #<Role id: 1, name: "1">]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As long as the appended role is an ActiveRecord object, what you are doing:

```
user.roles << role
```

Should de-duplicate automatically for `:has_many` associations.

For `has_many :through`, try:

```
class User
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles do
    def <<(new_item)
      super( Array(new_item) - proxy_association.owner.roles )
    end
  end
end
```

if super doesn't work, you may need to set up an alias_method_chain.

Comment: It doesn't work like that.  I'll update the post to include the test.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the association extension.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks!  The part I was missing when I tried something like this myself was the proxy_owner bit.

Comment: For posterity, the above method can be shortened and genericized to:

    def <<(*items)
      super(items - proxy_target)
    end

Comment: That was my first version :). I didn't have actual models set up and was concerned that super(nil) might cause errors. updating the answer with your version and leaving the sub-par code here ( for posterity ): def <<(*items); new_items = items - proxy_owner.roles; super( new_items ) unless new_items.empty?; end

Comment: For Rails 3.1, `s/proxy_owner/proxy_association.owner/`  [related Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001810/alternative-method-for-proxy-owner-in-activerecord)

Comment: Why make the argument `*items` when `<<` takes only a single object? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C

Comment: It's an easy way to transparently convert the added item to an array.  I'll update it with the new idioms.

Comment: It's odd to me that << dedupes for `has_many` but not `has_many :through`. However a Rails issue to fix this (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8573) was rejected with "This is your domain logic so it your responsibility to check it."

Comment: @Turadg Now `<<` can take more than one argument http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-object

Answer (score 29):

#### Use Array's [`|=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) Join Method.

You can use Array's [`|=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-7C) join method to add an element to the Array, unless it is already present. Just make sure you wrap the element in an Array.

```ruby
role                  #=> #<Role id: 1, name: "1">

user.roles            #=> []

user.roles |= [role]  #=> [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">]

user.roles |= [role]  #=> [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">]
```

Can also be used for adding multiple elements that may or may not already be present:

```ruby
role1                         #=> #<Role id: 1, name: "1">
role2                         #=> #<Role id: 2, name: "2">

user.roles                    #=> [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">]

user.roles |= [role1, role2]  #=> [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">, #<Role id: 2, name: "2">]

user.roles |= [role1, role2]  #=> [#<Role id: 1, name: "1">, #<Role id: 2, name: "2">]
```

Found this technique on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797217/293280).

Comment: Correct and most clean answer in my opinion

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of validates_uniqueness_of and overriding << in the main model, though this will also catch any other validation errors in the join model.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:role_id]

class User
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles do
    def <<(*items)
      super(items) rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Couldn't you change that exception to `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`? I like this answer. Be aware of [race conditions](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) though.

Comment: Nice answer. I used it without `validates_uniqueness_of`, having declared unique index in database and works charmingly.

Answer (score 2):

i think the proper validation rule is in your users_roles join model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:role_id]
```

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't actually do what I want though (which is a set-like behavior), and I've clarified what that is in the original post. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: I think this is the best answer for your problem. If you are careful in creating your interface, a user would have to hack it to add the wrong role anyway, in which case a validation exception is a totally suitable response.

Comment: Heh, are you crazy?  Users don't add their own roles :-)

The typical use case is that a user becomes a member of a role as a side effect of something else.  For example, buying a particular product.  Other products may also provide the same role, so there is a chance for duplication there.  I'd rather do the duplication checking in one place than in whatever random places need to ensure a user has a role.  In this sense, giving a user a role he already has is NOT an error condition.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and ended up using [#replace](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-replace), which "will perform a diff and delete/add only records that have changed".

Therefore, you need to pass the union of the existing roles (so they don't get deleted) and your new role(s):

```
new_roles = [role]
user.roles.replace(user.roles | new_roles)
```

It's important to note that both this answer and the accepted one are loading the associated `roles` objects into memory in order to perform the Array diff (`-`) and union (`|`). This could lead to performance issues if you're dealing with a large number of associated records.

If that's a concern, you may want to look into options that check for existence via queries first, or use an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (mysql) type query for inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is possible to create the validation rule

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_roles
```

then catch the validation exception and carry on gracefully. However, this feels really hacky and is very inelegant, if even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like:

```
user.roles.find_or_create_by(role_id: role.id) # saves association to database
user.roles.find_or_initialize_by(role_id: role.id) # builds association to be saved later
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create only one association in the database even if called multiple times [Refer rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-and-belongs-to-many-collection-objects).

```
user.roles=[Role.first]
```