# Alternative method for proxy_owner in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

ActiveRecord proxy_owner is now deprecated and the explanation here is very vague on how to change it, so I'm not sure how to use it my case:
 http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books do
    def some_method
      proxy_owner.author
    end
  end
end
```

I get a warning when I run this code that proxy_owner is deprecated:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling record.books.proxy_owner is deprecated. Please use record.association(:books).owner instead.
```

I can replace proxy_owner.author with:

```
@associaton.owner.author
```

This works; however, it seems dangerous. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it's safer to send `:owner` to `proxy_association` instead:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books do
    def some_method
      proxy_association.owner.author
    end
  end
end
```

The use of `proxy_association` is now mentioned in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions):

> However, inside the actual extension code, you will not have access to
>   the record (record.association(:items).owner) as above. In this case, you can access proxy_association.
>   For example, record.association(:items) and
>   record.items.proxy_association will return the same object, allowing
>   you to make calls like proxy_association.owner inside association
>   extensions.

Comment: This is what I expected as well, but it doesn't seem to work. I get an undefined method "proxy_association" error.

Comment: The previous comment applies to Rails 3.0. "proxy_owner" is fine in Rails 3.0. It's deprecated in Rails 3.1, though, and in Rails 3.1, Dave Nolan's answer is correct.