# Rails active record query: Find records on one side of a has_many :through that haven't been used with a particular record on the other side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a has_many :through relationship set up like so

```
class Situation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :notiftypes, through: :notifications
end

class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :situation
  belongs_to :notiftype
end

class Notiftype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :situations, through: :notifications
end
```

So, a Situation has many Notifications, which can be of many types (Notiftype).

My problem is trying to query for the `notiftypes` that have not been set for a particular `situation`.

[Want to find records with no associated records in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3)

The answers in that question get me close, but only to the point of finding Notiftypes that have not been set AT ALL.

If this were the standard `:situation` has_many `:notiftypes` I could just do a Left Outer Join like so

```
myquery = Notiftype.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN situations ON situations.notiftype_id = notiftype.id').where('notiftype_id IS NULL')
```

but I'm really not sure how to do this with the intermediate table between them.

I have been trying consecutive joins but it's not working. I'm not sure how to join the two separated tables.

Can anyone explain the right way to query the db?  I am using SQLite, Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.9.2 right now, but likely Postgresql in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Situation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :notiftypes, through: :notifications do

    def missing(reload=false)
      @missing_notiftypes = nil if reload
      @missing_notiftypes ||= proxy_owner.notiftype_ids.empty? ?
        Notiftype.all : 
        Notiftype.where("id NOT IN (?)", proxy_owner.notiftype_ids)
    end
  end
end
```

Now to get the missing Notiftype

```
situation.notiftypes.missing
```

If you want to further optimize this to use one SQL rather than two you can do the following:

```
class Situation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :notiftypes, through: :notifications do

    def missing(reload=false)
      @missing_notiftypes = nil if reload
      @missing_notiftypes ||= Notiftype.joins("
          LEFT OUTER JOIN (#{proxy_owner.notiftypes.to_sql}) A
          ON A.id = notiftypes.id").
        where("A.id IS NULL")
    end
  end
end
```

You can access the missing Notifytypes as:

```
situation.notiftypes.missing
```

Comment: Updated the answer with one SQL solution, take a look.

Comment: It works! I replaced proxy_owner with  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001810/alternative-method-for-proxy-owner-in-activerecord

Comment: Sorry... I hit enter early.  I replaced proxy_owner with proxy_association.owner based on this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001810/alternative-method-for-proxy-owner-in-activerecord

Is that necessary?  I wasn't getting any errors with the proxy_owner method, and they both work correctly.

Comment: My code is based on Rails 2.3.x, it looks like `proxy_owner` is deprecated.

Comment: gotcha. As I said, proxy_assocation.owner works for me on 3.1.1

Comment: The method wasn't working when a situation had no notiftypes.  I added an if statement, and it's working.  Can you review it in the answer below?  I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: I have updated the answer to address the empty list scenario. If you use my 2nd solution this problem will not arise.