# Add element to an array if it's not there already

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby class

```
class MyClass
  attr_writer :item1, :item2
end

my_array = get_array_of_my_class() #my_array is an array of MyClass
unique_array_of_item1 = []
```

I want to push `MyClass#item1` to `unique_array_of_item1`, but only if `unique_array_of_item1` doesn't contain that `item1` yet. There is a simple solution I know: just iterate through `my_array` and check if `unique_array_of_item1` already contains the current `item1` or not.

Is there any more efficient solution?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) instead of Array.

Comment: While it is true that the docs say that Sets are not order, they are in fact (as of Ruby 1.9) ordered. If you look at the code, the main methods you'd use to get at the order (such as `Set#each` and `Set#to_a`) delegate to `@hash`. And as of Ruby 1.9 Hashes are ordered. "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted." http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Hash.html

Comment: Never new there was such a thing as a set. They are awesome, thank you so much

Answer (score 164):

[@Coorasse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837638/coorasse) has a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18331074/293280), though it should be:

```
my_array | [item]
```

And to update `my_array` in place:

```
my_array |= [item]
```

Comment: or `my_array |= [item]` which will update `my_array` in place

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but the |= operator doesn't seem to work for me? I'm running Ruby 2.1.1

Comment: @Viet `|=` works just fine in my tests with 2.1.1.  Please describe your test case or open a new question.

Comment: Testing it again and it works now. Don't know what I was doing earlier since my comment was made many months ago.

Comment: What's the complexity of this?

Answer (score 42):

You don't need to iterate through `my_array` by hand.

```
my_array.push(item1) unless my_array.include?(item1)
```

Edit:

As Tombart points out in his comment, using `Array#include?` is not very efficient. I'd say the performance impact is negligible for small Arrays, but you might want to go with `Set` for bigger ones.

Comment: you definitely don't wanna do that! `array.include?(item)` has complexity `O(n)` - so it's like iterating the whole array. have a look at this benchmark: https://gist.github.com/deric/4953652

Comment: Beautiful solution :). Readable!
In my case, I cannot have a set, so I'm using this solution.

Comment: You can also use binary search to increase the performance if the array is ordered. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].bsearch { |e| e == 3 }`

Answer (score 35):

You can convert item1 to array and join them:

```
my_array | [item1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Important to keep in mind that the Set class and the | method (also called "Set Union") will yield an array of *unique* elements, which is great if you want no duplicates but which will be an unpleasant surprise if you have non-unique elements in your original array by design.

If you have at least one duplicate element in your original array that you don't want to lose, iterating through the array with an early return is worst-case O(n), which isn't too bad in the grand scheme of things.

```
class Array
  def add_if_unique element
    return self if include? element
    push element
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's perfect solution, but worked for me:

```
    host_group = Array.new if not host_group.kind_of?(Array)
    host_group.push(host)
```

Comment: This did not work for you, unless uniqueness isn't a constraint. It does not *uniquely* add elements to the array.
>> a = [1,2,3];
=> [1, 2, 3]
>> a.push(3);
=> [1, 2, 3, 3]
>> a.push(3);
=> [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>> a.push(3);
=> [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]