# Automatically create relationship unless it already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :catbowls
    has_many :bowls, through: :catbowls
end

class CatBowl < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cats
    belongs_to :bowls
end

class Bowl < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :catbowls
    has_many :cats, through: :catbowls
end
```

In the rails console I can give a bowl to a cat:

```
cat = Cat.create(name: 'tibbles')
bowl = Bowl.create(color: 'blue')
cat.catbowls #=> []
cat.catbowls.create(bowl_id: bowl.id)
cat.catbowls #=> [#<Bowl id: 1, color: "blue", created_at: "2014-04-23 22:53:15", updated_at: "2014-04-23 22:53:15">]
```

This makes sense, and the following association exists:

```
CatBowl.all #=> [#<Bowl id: 1, cat_id: 1, bowl_id: 1>]
```

**However,** here's my problem. If I create the association again, it doesn't actually change the result, but I do get an ineffectual identical catbowl relationship.

```
cat.catbowls.create(bowl_id: bowl.id)
cat.catbowls #=> [#<Bowl id: 1, color: "blue", created_at: "2014-04-23 22:53:15", updated_at: "2014-04-23 22:53:15">]>
```

This relationship is identical to the previous one and utterly useless:

```
CatBowl.all #=> [#<Bowl id: 1, cat_id: 1, bowl_id: 1>,#<Bowl id: 2, cat_id: 1, bowl_id: 1>]
```

So how can I stop an existing relationship from being created? What method chain should be used to replace **cat.catbowls.create**, and create a relationship **unless** it already exists?

I could use an unless statement  to do this,

```
cat.catbowls.create(bowl_id: bowl.id) unless Catbowl.where(cat_id: cat.id, bowl_id:bowl.id).present?
```

however this is pretty cumbersome and results in a lot of queries. What I want to do is so common I'm wondering if some rails magic can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `find_or_create_by` is the answer:

```
Catbowl.find_or_create_by(cat_id: cat.id, bowl_id: bowl.id )
```

By passing the method the options `cat_id` and `bowl_id`, we check for uniqueness concerning only those columns, and ignoring all other columns (such as the `id`).

Comment: Just FYI: 
`Please note *this method is not atomic*, it runs first a SELECT, and if there are no results an INSERT is attempted. If there are other threads or processes there is a race condition between both calls and it could be the case that you end up with two similar records.`
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by

Comment: These days consider `create_or_find_by` instead. See: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create_or_find_by

Answer (score 1):

first remove 's' to cats and bowl do
class CatBowl < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cat
    belongs_to :bowl
end

then create bridge entry

**cat.bowls << bowl**

but it can not prevent repetition. 
to prevent repetition handle with conditions

condition may likes:  **`(cat.bowls.find_by(id: bowl.id) || cat.bowls <<  bowl) if rails 4`**

**(cat.bowls.find_by_id(bowl.id) || cat.bowls <<  bowl) if rails 3**

Comment: Surprising this Rails bug isn't fixed yet.  Someone tried, referenced in comments here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315109/rails-idiom-to-avoid-duplicates-in-has-many-through , but no dice.  A unique index on the join-table in the DB level will prevent the duplicate, but also throw an error - but better an error than garbage in the DB.  This kludge seems the best we have to avoid throwing the error, until this bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat = Cat.create(name: 'tibbles')
bowl = Bowl.create(color: 'blue')
```

to simply associate the bowl to the cat:

```
cat.bowls << bowl
```

associate the bowl to cat, but check if relationship exists first:

```
cat.bowls << bowl unless cat.bowl_ids.include?(bowl.id)
```