# rails, accepts_nested and has_many :through is creating duplicate entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a store model that has many products with a has_many :through relationship.

I have this working with accepts_nested_attributes, but the result is that rails is making duplicate associates.

I don't have anything special going on it is a very simple app.

Any ideas on why duplicates associates are getting created?

Comment: please post your code you write so far.

Comment: let me work on it a little more and then I will post. I was just checking if anyone knows about a bug

Comment: Does this come after a page refresh by any chance?

Comment: @lukas, id does not come after a page refresh.

Comment: I changed the association to just a has_many instead of with :through => and that fixed the problem. It was creating double entries with a nested nested attribute. My code was not very good so I didn't add much else to this question. You can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in Rails, with a fix set to be included in 2.3.6.

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3575-multiple-join-records-when-using-nested_attributes-in-habtm

Answer (score 1):

look at answer : [how to avoid duplicates in a has_many :through relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315792/how-to-avoid-duplicates-in-a-has-many-through-relationship/318146#318146) here :

add :uniq => true to the has_many :through

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :readers, :through => :blogs_readers, :uniq => true
end

class Reader < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :blogs_readers, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :blogs, :through => :blogs_readers, :uniq => true
end

class BlogsReaders < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :reader
end
```