# Unique list through a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unique, has-many-through, has-many

I have 3 Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_memberships
  has_many :team_memberships
end

class Teams < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :team_memberships
  has_many :team_memberships

  has_many :clubs, :through => :club_memberships
  has_many :club_memberships
end

class Clubs < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, :through => :club_memberships
  has_many :club_memberships
end
```

I want to be able to get a unique list of clubs that the user is a member of. If I have the following:

```
@teams = User.last.teams
```

How can I get a list of clubs that these teams are members of. If there are any duplicates I would like to only show them once in the list.

Currently if I do:

```
<% @user.teams.each do |t| %>
  <% t.clubs.each do |c| %>
    <%= link_to c.name, c %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I obviously get a complete list but I want to remove the duplicates. Can anyone offer a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can just set up a relationship like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :clubs, -> { uniq }, :through => :teams

end
```

and then reference:

```
<% @user.clubs.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if there is a better way!

Comment: Didn't work for me because I'm using Rails 5 not Rails 4.
`NoMethodError:  undefined method \`extensions' for #<Array:0x0000000007b22918>       Did you mean?  extend`  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/318146/10245 - use `distinct` instead of `uniq`